# How to manually re-create Ingress parts (Backend name is generated randomly for k8s Service)?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-gcp

I wanted avoid using k8s Ingress on GKE, and instead manage all the proxies/rules/certificates manually through Terraform, and not through K8S. But the missing link is how would I get k8s Service name for creating a LoadBalancer Backend service? It seems to be created with random suffix, so it's not possible to hardcode it to Terraform configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, sounds like you want to create the load balancer yourself (via Terraform) and not have it managed via K8S ingress?

I'd suggest taking a look at using [standalone NEGs with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#how_to) services.  A NEG (which is a named resource) can be the backend for a LoadBalancer and can map to the pod endpoints backing a Service.  You'd create a K8S Service resource, for example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: NEG_DEMO_SVC
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"80":{"name": "NEG_NAME"}}}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    run: NEG_DEMO_APP # Selects Pods labelled run: NEG_DEMO_APP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9376
```

You'd then be able to create a [GCE loadbalancer with a backend that uses the NEG](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#attaching_a_load_balancer_to_your_standalone_negs) and you'd have the name of the NEG since you'd pass that in when creating the Service resource.  No Ingress involved.

Comment: Thanks, the trick seems to be in `cloud.google.com/neg` annotation for Service -- that's a bridge between K8S and GCP load balancers.